# blpapi formula working in excel but not in R

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi, rblpapi, bloomapi

I am trying to substitute some excels that we were using to retrieve some data from bloomberg, with a script in R that can automate some tasks.

Usually with rblpapi I can use the same commands that works for Excel in R, but I have founded one that does not. The following command in Excel:

```
=BDP("ABG SM Equity" ; "ARD_NET_INC" ; "FUND_PER=C")
```

returns the number I need, but if I try this one in R:

```
bdp( "ABG SM Equity"  , "ARD_NET_INC", "FUND_PER=C")
```

it sends the error message:

Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides, verbose,  : 
  Request options must be named.

I have tried `options= c("FUND_PER","C")` and many possible combinations but it returns error messages like:

Attempt to access unknown sub-element 'FUND_PER' on element 'ReferenceDataRequest'

How do I specify the option properly or just get that data from the request?

I am using R 3.4.0 on windows.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code did the trick:

```
    bdp( "ABG SM Equity"  , "ARD_NET_INC", overrides =  c("FUND_PER"="C"))
```

I just needed to use overrides instead of options.